How do I look for the 7shape in the game of Connect 4 using bitboards for each player?
The shape I am looking for looks like this:

I have two bitboards that represent two players in the game Connect 4. The bits that are used are bits from 0 to 48, so 49 bits in total. The representation looks like this:
  6 13 20 27 34 41 48   55 62     Additional row
+---------------------+ 
| 5 12 19 26 33 40 47 | 54 61     top row
| 4 11 18 25 32 39 46 | 53 60
| 3 10 17 24 31 38 45 | 52 59
| 2  9 16 23 30 37 44 | 51 58
| 1  8 15 22 29 36 43 | 50 57
| 0  7 14 21 28 35 42 | 49 56 63  bottom row
+---------------------+

The top row is not being used for anything particular, but this setup makes it easier to check for wins. There are 7 columns and 6 rows as in the game of Connect 4.
The bits are structured as follows:
... 0000000 0000000 0000010 0000011 0000000 0000000 0000000 // encoding Xs
... 0000000 0000000 0000001 0000100 0000001 0000000 0000000 // encoding Os
      col 6   col 5   col 4   col 3   col 2   col 1   col 0

So we use 7 bits for each column, we ignore the last bit in each column as there are only 6 rows per column.
The position in the picture can be represented with two bits.
Red (player 1) bitboard: 101000011000001100000000. The most significant bit here is the middle column move at the bottom. The first move that red made in the middle of the board.
Here is the bitboard for player 0 (yellow): 1010000000100000010000001. The least significant bit here is the leftmost move by yellow at the bottom of the board.
In order to confirm this 7shape, we need to check that all reds pieces exists, the way it is drawn on the picture, but at the same time make sure that the two crossed positions are not full, but empty.
With this I am able to identify the 7 shape, but I don't know how to check if the two crossed spots are empty, I only know how to check if red has not played there.
is7Trap(bitboard, player) {
    const bp = bitboard[player];
    const bo = bitboard[1 - player];
    const shapeExists = (bp & (bp >> 2n) & (bp << 5n) & (bp << 6n) & (bp << 12n)) !== 0n;
    const topSpotRedFree = (bp & (bp >> 2n) & (bp << 5n) & (bp << 6n) & (bp << 12n) & (bp << 18n)) === 0n;
    const bottomSpotRedFree = (bp & (bp >> 2n) & (bp << 5n) & (bp << 6n) & (bp << 12n) & (bp << 19n)) === 0n;
    console.log("shapeExists", shapeExists);
    console.log("topSpotRedFree", topSpotRedFree);
    console.log("bottomSpotRedFree", bottomSpotRedFree);
    console.log(bp.toString(2));
    console.log(bo.toString(2));
    if (shapeExists && topSpotRedFree && bottomSpotRedFree) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;        
}

I don't know how to check if yellow also has not played there.

Check bits i, i - 6, i - 12, i - 5 and i + 2.

Can you show an example in javascript?

I don't really understand what you mean

Was the code above AI generated or are you still learning? Just curious because you're using bits and binary manipulation, so they seem to have expected you'd know about bit masking.

Check bits 9 (i - 12), 15 (i - 6), 16(i - 5), 21 (i) and 23 (i + 2). If you want code examples, provide at least a [mcve] of your code. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions, not a code writing service.

I have now. I can identify the 7 shape as red player, also check that red has not played on the two crossed marks. But I don't know how to simultaneously also check that yellow has not played there. The two crossed marks must be unplayed for both players.

You can complete your is7Trap function with the following idea:

shapeExists calculates the position of the bottom of the "7" if there is one (or multiple, if there are more than one). You should not have to recalculate that again in the next assignments, so instead of immediately turning it into a boolean, keep that bit pattern and don't compare it yet with 0n.

<< 18n is the correct shift for the top of the two spots that should be free, but you should not perform an & operation here. Instead, take the bit you found in the previous step and shift it in the opposite direction (>> 18n) to the spot you want to test, and then test it against (bp | bp) which represents the occupied cells. If this result is 0n, then you know that spot is free.

As you have a dummy row at the top, you should make sure the upper free spot isn't on it, as you would get a false positive for it (neither player has a disc there, so it would wrongly count as "free")


Here is the adaptation of your function:
const DUMMY_ROW = 0b1000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000n;

function is7Trap(bitboard, player) {
    const bp = bitboard[player];
    const bo = bitboard[1 - player];
    // Shift (with 18n) the bottom(s) of the found "7" shape(s) to the top spot(s) that should be free
    const topSpot = (bp & (bp >> 2n) & (bp << 5n) & (bp << 6n) & (bp << 12n)) >> 18n;
    const shapeExists = topSpot !== 0n;
    // Verify that the spot and the one below it are both free:
    const bothSpotsFree = ((bo | bp | DUMMY_ROW) & (topSpot | (topSpot >> 1n))) === 0n;
    console.log("shapeExists", shapeExists);
    console.log("bothSpotsFree", bothSpotsFree);
    return shapeExists && bothSpotsFree;
}

Generalisation
It will lead to a lot of code if you are going to check all types of  arrow-shapes. Realise that there are upside-down 7 shapes, X shapes, or shapes where the two free spots are between columns that have the discs that make the threats, like for instance in these examples where asterisks highlight the two free spots:
. . . X . . .     . . . . . . .     . . . . . . . 
. . . X . . .     . . . . . . .     . . . . . . .
. . . O . . .     . . . . . O .     . . O . X O .
O * O O . . .     . . . . * X X     . . X * O X .
X * X O . . .     . . X O * O O     . . X * O X .
O . X X . . .     . X O O . X X     . . O . X O .

To detect all these variations with the approach you have taken is going to be a enormous task.
My guess is that you don't only want to look for particular shapes, but actually want to detect two threats on top of each other, no matter how these two threats are "supported" by the already played discs.
I would suggest that you have threat detection set up, and possibly it is more interesting to keep that information incrementally updated as moves are made, than to have to recalculate that each time from scratch.
To know where the threats are, it will be helpful to introduce the concept of groups, i.e. all possible sets of four cells that represent a winning combination if ever one player can occupy all four of them. Then incrementally keep track for each group which cells are still free, which are occupied by the first player, and which by the second player. If a move results in a group that has three of its cells occupied by the same player, then you know that the only remaining free cell is a threat. You could flag this cell in a bitmap reserved for threats; one per player -- just like the bitboard you have for the already played discs.
Here is a runnable implementation in JavaScript. It has some preprocessing going on in a static block to identify all the groups and the cells in those groups. I realise I might not have used the exact same representation as you might have, but it should not be difficult to translate this to your set up:


class Connect4 {
    static {
        // Two static variables:
        this.cellToGroups = Array.from({length: 7*7}, () => []);
        this.groupToCells = [];
        
        const register = (row, col, shift) => {
            let cellId = row + col * 7;
            const group = [];
            // Collect the four cells that make up the group
            // And for each cell add a the id of the group it is in
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                group.push(cellId);
                this.cellToGroups[cellId].push(this.groupToCells.length);
                cellId += shift;
            }
            this.groupToCells.push(group);
        };
        // All vertical groups
        for (let row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                register(row, col, 1);
            }
        }
        // All horizontal groups
        for (let row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                register(row, col, 7);
            }
        }
        // All diagonal groups
        for (let row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                register(row, col, 8);
                register(5 - row, col, 6);
            }
        }
    }
    constructor() {
        this.bitboard = [0n, 0n];
        this.heights = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        // For each group: array with cells taken by X, taken by O, taken by neither
        this.groupOccupation = Connect4.groupToCells.map(cells => [[], [], [...cells]]); 
        this.threats = [0n, 0n]; // Same structure as bitboard: a 1 indicates a winning move (if reachable)
        this.moves = []; // History of played moves (columns)
    }
    move(col) {
        const row = this.heights[col];
        if (row == 6) throw "Invalid move";
        const player = this.moves.length % 2;
        const cellId = row + col * 7;
        const bit = 1n << BigInt(cellId);
        this.heights[col]++;
        this.bitboard[player] |= bit;
        // Incrementally update the occupation this player has in the groups
        //    that this cell is part of
        for (const groupId of Connect4.cellToGroups[cellId]) {
            const group = this.groupOccupation[groupId];
            // In this group, mark the cell as taken by this player
            let i = group[2].indexOf(cellId);
            group[player].push(...group[2].splice(i, 1));
            // Check if this group is completed or becomes a threat
            if (group[player].length === 4) this.gameOver = true;
            if (group[player].length === 3 && group[2].length) { // Making a threat!
                this.threats[player] |= 1n << BigInt(group[2][0]);
            }
        }
        this.moves.push(col);
    }
    toString() {
        return Array.from({length: 6}, (_, top) =>
            Array.from({length: 7}, (_, col) => {
                const bit = BigInt(5 - top + col * 7);
                return (this.bitboard[0] >> bit) & 1n ? "X" 
                     : (this.bitboard[1] >> bit) & 1n ? "O" 
                     // Output the threats with small letters
                     : (this.threats[0] >> bit) & 1n ? "x"
                     : (this.threats[1] >> bit) & 1n ? "o"
                     : ".";
            }).join(" ")
        ).join("\n");
    }
}

// Demo
const game = new Connect4();
const moves = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4];
for (const move of moves) game.move(move);
console.log("" +game);



The toString method renders threats with lowercase letters. As you can see in this example run, there are two threats on top of each other for player "O" in the third column. This information is readily available in the this.threats bitmaps.
Note that both players could have a threat on the same cell. I did not provide for displaying that in the toString method, but that is not essential. The this.threats bitmaps provide for that possibility.

Thank you again for helping me. I appreciate it alot. I will study your code. But for learning reasons, how would I detect the 7 shape with the two spots crossed as empty as in the question? I can detect the 7 shape as red player by shifting bits. But I don't know how to check if yellow has not played there. I am asking for learning purposes. I am new to bitboards and bit manipulation.

Also I provided the js code for identifying the 7 shape with the two crossed spots as red, but I have no idea how to detect that yellow has not also played there, that the two spots that are crossed are empty.

I have added at the top of my answer the suggested update to your function, and added more examples of other shapes that you'd want to detect, which illustrate how that becomes a huge task. That's why I propose a different approach, which the snippet demonstrates.

Thank you so much for this, you have no idea how much you make my day better. I started to develop connect 4 ai as coping mechanism, and days like these when I have progress like this makes my day so much better! Thank you! For both explaining how to make faster code, and for advising me to generalize the whole process and pointing out all different shapes.

You're welcome. I just realised you could get a false positive when the upper free spot happens to be on the dummy row, so I made an update to the first part of my answer.

I understand what you mean. Since the dummy row will always be empty, we might hit there with the empty spots. Again thank you so much. Greetings from Norway

Btw, I just bought you a coffee to show my appreciation. Have a good one!

I bought another one. This time I did not forget to send greetings message  ^_^. Have a nice day

Much appreciated! Enjoy your day!

I think you inititally also posted an undo function if I am not mistaken. How come you removed it? I use undo in the minmax PVS search, in place modification tends to be better than cloning the state when doing searches.

I removed it because it didn't relate to your question and I hadn't used it nor tested it, and didn't intend to post it from the start.
